# How to use javascript split in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Very new to Javascript and have been searching the webs for assistance, but haven't quite found a solution.

I am attempting to use javascript to split/remove the output of a particular field. The data in the survey is being pulled from our school's database after a user logs in to the survey via shibboleth.  All the information is being displayed, so that part works, but one particular field is appending an email address (@email.com) to a field.

I want to omit this part from being displayed. Either my javascript is incorrect or the javascript is not being loaded/read.  The javascript code was borrowed from a colleague and it works on his surveys, but he has a lot of other things going on in his survey and this works for him.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/
    var iid = "${e://Field/theUTIID}";
    var split_array = iid.split("@",1);
    var eid = split_array[0];
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('theUTIID', eid);

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/
    var iid = "${e://Field/theUTIID}";
    var split_array = iid.split("@",1);
    var eid = split_array[0];
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('theUTIID', eid);

});
```

I have this in both the Onload and OnReady for testing.  Doesn't matter if I have this is one location or the other, I am not getting the desired results.

I only have one question on the survey (it's just a test survey) and so the javascript code is with the first and only question.

Survey Question has the following in a text entry.  Again, output is displayed, but need the @email.com to removed from the EID field.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add some examples of what the output looks like?

Comment: Both of these two functions do the same thing. Can you condense them into one? Or just pick one to use.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct (other than it only needs to be in one or the other function). I'm guessing it isn't a problem with the code, but where you are trying to pipe the embedded variable. The JavaScript above has to be attached to a question on a separate page before the place where you want to pipe it.

Add a page break, then pipe theUTIID into a question on the next page.